# Change from to-day to today

Tags: history

In old books, people often use the spelling "to-day" instead of "today". When did the change happen? Also, when people wrote "to-day", did they feel, when pronouncing the word, that it contained two words, rather than a single concept?

Comment: I imagine they felt exactly as I feel when pronouncing "e-mail" as opposed to "email". (Not especially different.)

Comment: I've noticed the word separation in old literature, for example the King James version of the Bible in Matthew 6 you'll see "to day" and "to morrow".  https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew+6%3A28-34&version=KJV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Five minutes of research brings...

*today

O.E. todæge, to dæge "on (the) day," from to "at, on" (see to) + dæge, dative of dæg "day" (see day). [Generally written as two words until 16c., after which it usually was written to-day until early 20c.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=today&searchmode=nl)*

*Similar constructions exist in other Germanic languages (cf. Du. van daag "from-day," Dan., Swed. i dag "in day"). Ger. heute is from O.H.G. hiutu, from P.Gmc. hiu tagu "on (this) day," with first element from PIE pronomial stem ki-, represented by L. cis "on this side."*

The same applies to *tomorrow* and *tonight*, at least according to this dictionary.

Comment: Yes, but how did people *feel* when pronouncing the word(s)?

Comment: They felt a warm thrill of confusion, followed by a space-cadet glow.

Comment: That's _to-boldly-day_.

Comment: Here is evidence that the spelling 'to-day' was still being used in Canada in the 1950's. From The Canadian Jewish Review - Jan 2, 1953:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2M95.png

Answer (score 3):

I grew up writing 'to-day' and 'week-end' (in 1950s' Britain).  Common pairings of words seem, first, to be linked with a hyphen, then to become one word.  I did not feel any differently about 'to-day' than I do these days about 'today'.